# Chrome open selectbox set cursor to text

Tags: css, google-chrome, cursor

Do you know why Chrome sets cursor's shape into the "text" one, when over an open selectbox ?
If I set the CSS to:

```
select {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

It sets the cursor when the mouse is over the selectbox, but when you click to open the list, it comes back to the "text" shape again.

Do you know how to change it to a pointer or something else when the selectbox is open ?

Thanks!

Mickael.

Comment: It appears that I have this problem only on linux, not Windows, so I assume it's a temporary pb caused by Chrome itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being able to actually style the options of a select box is something **[supported differently by different browser](http://home.tiscali.nl/developerscorner/fdc-varia/styling-dropdown-boxes.htm#options)**. If this does not work in Chrome, it does not seem to support that.